# How to pass extra parameters to a NavigationGuardNext call on Vue Router

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I was trying to make a middleware (multi-guard) system with Vue Router and it was going well until I had a need to know the origin route on the middleware function and discover that I can't pass the from and to parameters from beforeEach function to callback with NavigationGuardNext.

The idea is to use Vue Router beforeEach, to grab possible middlewares (guards) from meta parameters defined in the routes.

Here is a route example:

```
 {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'home',
        meta: {
            middleware: [ auth, isAdmin ]
        },
        component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue')
  }
```

Here are router beforeEach call:

```
router.beforeEach((to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized, next: NavigationGuardNext) => {
    if (!to.meta.middleware) {  
        return next()
    }

    return middlewarePipeline(to.meta.middleware, next, to, from)
})
```

This is the middleware pipeline:

```
import { NavigationGuardNext, RouteLocationNormalized } from "vue-router";

const middlewarePipeline = function(middlewares: Array<any>, next: NavigationGuardNext, to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized) {
    const middlewaresLeft = middlewares.slice(0);
    const nextMiddleware = middlewaresLeft.shift();

    if (!nextMiddleware) {
        next()
    }

    nextMiddleware((nextArg: NavigationGuardNext) => { 
        if (!nextArg) {
            return middlewarePipeline(middlewaresLeft, next, to, from);
        }

        return next(nextArg);
    })
}

export default middlewarePipeline;
```

And here are the implementation of the auth middleware (or guard):

```
import { useAuthStore } from "@/stores/authStore";
import type { NavigationGuardNext, RouteLocationNormalized } from "vue-router";

export default function auth(next: NavigationGuardNext, to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized) {
    const authStore = useAuthStore() 
    
    if (!authStore.authUser.token) {
        if (to === 'admin-home') {
            return next({
                name: 'admin-login'
            })
        } else {
            return next({
                name: 'user-login'
            })
        } 
    }

    return next()
}
```

My goal is to get the parameters to and from here on the middleware implementation in order to make a decision based on the origin of the request.

This need came out when we introduce the Admin/User profiles. Once an ordinary user makes a request to a page that is protected, I need to return the user to the proper login screen for example. (admin-login when trying to access an admin route, and user-login when trying to access a regular user route).

Does anyone know a way to pass these parameters transparently?